# Erro ao adicionar e remover classe Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

Eu criei um script para adicionar e remover uma classe, ela funciona, mas as vezes quando há essa troca de classse acontece esse erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`.

Alguém sabe dizer o que pode ser e se há uma solução? Por exemplo, quando acontecer o erro mostrar o último dado clicado, não sei.

```
  const selectMapID = document.querySelectorAll('.map a');
  const selectArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.map article');
  selectArticles[1].classList.add('ativo');

  selectMapID.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', showState);
  })

  function showState(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const element = event.target;
    const id = element.getAttribute('id');
    const article = document.getElementById(id);

    selectArticles.forEach( (section) => {
      section.classList.remove('ativo');
    } );
    article.classList.add('ativo');
  }
```

Comment: Qual a linha do erro?

Comment: Olhando o código, me parece que você está tentando pegar o id de um <a> clicado e adicionar a classe .ativo em um <article> com o mesmo id. Isso não vai dar certo mesmo. Coloque o código HTML tb para que possamos ver.

Comment: A ideia é essa mesmo, o problema é que preciso fazer isso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz pequenas modificações em seu código para que o erro não seja mais visto. Dê uma olhada:

```js
const selectMapID = document.querySelectorAll('.map a');
const selectArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.map article');

selectArticles[1].classList.add('ativo');

selectMapID.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', showState);
});

function showState(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const element = event.target;
  const id = element.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  const article = document.getElementById(id);

  selectArticles.forEach(section => {
    section.classList.remove('ativo');
  });
  article.classList.add('ativo');
}
```

```css
.ativo {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <article id="article1">Article I</article>
  <article id="article2">Article II</article>
  <article id="article3">Article III</article>
  <a href="#article1">I</a>
  <a href="#article2">II</a>
  <a href="#article3">III</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse código ajudou bastante, porque antes as informações desaparecia da tela quando dava o erro, mas ainda acontece um erro diferente Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null, mas pelo menos as informações não desaparecem

Comment: só para constar eu estou selecionando um mapa que esta em SVG.

Comment: @RandysMachado, você precisa adicionar o atributo `href` na tag `<a>` apontando para o `id` do `article` conforme o exemplo HTML que fiz.

Comment: sim, eu fiz isso!

Answer (score 1):

## Sobre o erro

O erro apresentado diz que não foi possível encontrar a propriedade classList de "null".

#### Por que a variável está com o valor "null"?

na linha:

```
const id = element.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
```

você tenta resgatar o valor do atribut "href" da âncora que foi clicada, e na linha seguinte:

```
 const article = document.getElementById(id);
```

você passa o valor recebido como parâmetro do médoto getElementById que por algum motivo retorna null, indicando que não existe nenhum elemento no DOM com esse id. As possíveis causas para isso podem ser:

1. erro de digitação - você pode ter digitado as mesmas palavras com letras em caixa alta/baixa no seu link, ou algum erro de digitação e no seu elemento que deve ser resgatado pelo getElementById o valor difere;
2. valor inexistente em alguma das referencias - você pode ter esquecido de colocar o id na âncora ou no elemento a ser resgatado pelo getElementById;

#### Solução

Apenas checar se os valores estão corretos em ambas as partes.

## Melhorias

Gostaria de sugerir algumas melhorias no seu código que podem ajudar em performance e evitar alguns possíveis bugs.

#### Evite realizar as mesmas tarefas em vão

Na função executada a cada click dados são armazenados e resgatados do dom, mas isso só deve acontecer a cada click de uma referencia "não ativa", por exemplo:

1. Imagine os as âncoras "A", "B" e "C" e a âncora "A" está ativa;
2. A função disparada pelo clique só deve executar as tarefas devidas se o clique vier das âncoras "B" ou "C" neste momento, pois "A" já está ativo e consequentemente sua referência também.

Exemplo:

```
const activeState = {
  previous: 0,
  current: 0,
};

function updateActiveState(current) {
  activeState.previous = activeState.current;
  activeState.current = current;
}

function onLinkClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = event.target;
  const eIndex = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-index'));

  if(activeState.current !== eIndex) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Neste exemplo eu criei um objeto para servir de "state" para saber que elemento está ativo atualmente e qual elemento foi clicado anteriormente.

> Benefício: centralização de dados diminuição de lógica para adicionar e/ou remover as classes.

#### Faça um cache dos elementos a serem manipulados

Na sua função executada a cada clique na linha:

```
const article = document.getElementById(id);
```

o DOM é requisitado para resgatar o elemento pelo seu id o que exige um certo uso de memória do browser.
Para melhorar isso, sugiro criar um cache no scopo anterior á função e usá-lo para resgatar esses elementos sempre que precisar ao invés de ir buscar no DOM novamente. Por exemplo:

```
// Resgata do DOM apenas uma vez o elemento que contém os artigos a serem manipulados
const articlesSection = document.querySelector('.articles');

// Resgata do Objeto em cache todos os elementos com a classe "article"
const articles = articlesSection.querySelectorAll('.article');

// Resgata do Objeto em cache o elemento com o id especificado
const article1 = articlesSection.querySelector('#article1');
const article2 = articlesSection.getElementById('#article2');
```

> Benefícios: performance

Seque o exemplo com as melhorias aplicadas

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav .link');
const articlesSection = document.querySelector('.articles');
const articles = articlesSection.querySelectorAll('.article');

const activeState = {
  previous: 0,
  current: 0,
};

function updateActiveState(current) {
  activeState.previous = activeState.current;
  activeState.current = current;
}

function onLinkClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = event.target;
  const eIndex = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-index'));

  if(activeState.current !== eIndex) {
    updateActiveState(eIndex);

    const currentActive = activeState.current;
    const previousActive = activeState.previous;
    const currentRef = target.getAttribute('data-ref');
    const previousRef = links[previousActive].getAttribute('data-ref');
    const currentArticle = articlesSection.querySelector("#" + currentRef);
    const previousArticle = articlesSection.querySelector("#" + previousRef);
    const activeClass = 'active';

    target.classList.add(activeClass);
    links[previousActive].classList.remove(activeClass);
    
    currentArticle.classList.add(activeClass);
    previousArticle.classList.remove(activeClass); 
    
  }
}

links.forEach((link, idx) => {
  link.classList.add(idx === 0 ? 'active' : null);
  link.setAttribute('data-index', idx);
  link.addEventListener('click', onLinkClick);
});

articles.forEach((article, idx) => {
  article.classList.add(idx === 0 ? 'active' : null);
  article.setAttribute('data-index', idx);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100%;
}

nav, .articles {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  min-width: 150px;
}

nav .link, nav .link:visited {
  color: #cccccc;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .link:not(:nth-child(1)), nav .link:visited {
  border-top: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)
}

nav .link:hover, nav .link:visited:hover, nav .link.active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.articles {
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.articles .article:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.articles .article:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}


.article p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-ref="one">Lorem.</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-ref="two">Ullam?</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-ref="three">Amet.</a>
  </nav>
  
  <section class="articles">
    <div class="article" id="one">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, laboriosam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" id="two">
      <p>Ab explicabo voluptatibus corporis quas aliquid officiis ratione accusamus unde.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" id="three">
      <p>Exercitationem assumenda quis quidem, est sapiente nihil provident at sunt!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara muito foda a tua resposta, vou analizar cada passo e começar a utilizar.

Comment: Sucesso, rapaz!